# How to create a new R vector by filtering with grepl()?

Tags: r, vector, filter, grepl

This is a straightforward problem, but I'm missing something below.

I have a very large vector of filepaths (i.e. strings) in R

```
vec = c("\dir\subdir\pathname1\file.txt", "\dir\subdir\pathname1\file.pdf",
                                           ...,  "\dir\subdir\pathname9\file.jpg")
```

My idea is to create a `data.table` object for each "type" of file, e.g. `.txt`, `.pdf`, etc. Therefore, I need an R vector for each file extension by filtering the above.

The way I would search for strings with certain extensions is `grepl()`:

```
grepl(".txt$", vec)
```

Now, how do I create a new vector using grepl()? The end point should be

```
txt_paths <- # single vector only with txt files
pdf_paths <- # single vector only with pdf files
jpg_paths <- # single vector only with jpg files
etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the logical vector produced by grepl() to index vec.

```
txt_paths <- vec[grepl(".txt$", vec)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` the `vector` into a `list` of `vector`s

```
lst <- split(vec, tools::file_ext(vec))
names(lst) <- paste0(names(lst), "_paths")
```

It is not recommended to have individual objects in the global environment, but if we prefer that way, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

If we need to `split` by the file name,

```
lst2 <- split(vec, tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(vec)))
```

#### data

```
vec <- c("\\dir\\subdir\\pathname1\\file.txt", 
        "\\dir\\subdir\\pathname1\\file.pdf",
        "\\dir\\subdir\\pathname9\\file.jpg")
```

Comment: Let's say instead of only file extension, I want to filter by filename, e.g. all `file1` paths into a vector, all `file2` paths into a vector, etc. How would this be accomplished without `file_ext()`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang  Updated the post